# How to solve this PHP fatal error after installing module?

Tags: 7

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare _field_info_field_cache()
>   (previously declared in
>   C:\xxxx\wwwroot\xxxxx\modules\field\field.info.inc:16) in
>   C:\xxxxx\wwwroot\xxxxxxx\sites\all\modules\easy_booking-7.x-2.4\modules\field\field.info.inc
>   on line 32

So I got this error notification after turning on Error debug in my IIS Server because previously it only showed a 500 page error.

It seems it's calling two times the same function? Anyone can help?

Edit: I guess it's better I just delete the module but then I get a `require_once` error:

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '

Comment: The module is using a function that is part of core, which causes that bug. You may be able to use the module if you remove that function from the module, but I'd suspect you'll run into other problems if you do that. The best thing to do is open a ticket in the issue queue for that module, which can be found on the module download page.

Comment: Don't "simply" delete a module. Disable and uninstall it first. Otherwise Drupal will miss it.

Comment: @leymannx Sorry didnt see your post.  I couldnt disable it first because I couldnt access my admin page due to the require once fatal error.

Comment: What module did you install then? Custom? Contrib?

Comment: @leymannx It was "easy booking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution.

1. I run `update.php` as in typing `www.yourwebsite.com/update.php` in
   the browser
2. I upgraded my php version on my IIS Server from `PHP 5.3` to `PHP 5.5` ([For Windows users, install `PHP upgrade manager` for IIS and follow instructions](https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/using-php-manager-for-iis-to-setup-and-configure-php))

While doing this it still gave me a fatal PHP error about my elfinder module but I deleted a function in the given line code and after runing `update.php`, my admin page worked again.

Answer (score 2):

Put the module back. Check its code. Delete the problematic function named in the corresponding error message from it. Go to admin page. Uninstall the module.

Try to reinstall the module in a proper location. Don't name the folder `easy_booking-7.x-2.4`. Simply name it `easy_booking`. If the error still occurs, file a bug at https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/easy_booking?status=All&categories=All

Comment: Thanks. So I delete the whole function? The first problematic function in the error message is sites\all\modules\views\includes\plugins.inc:15)

Comment: No! From `easy_booking` module!

Comment: Your solution works. Although I can see my admin panel now, the module panel has disappeared which doesn't allow me to clean uninstall that problematic module.

Comment: @Vasmir - Any chance you can do it with Drush or Drupal Console? Finally you can try to edit the module's status database entry.

Comment: Drush, unfortunately -not on this machine. Where do I access the Drupal Console and what command line should I use?

Comment: Console is d8 only

Comment: Update: Admin Menu finally showed up BUT clicking on modules for ex. gives me new fatal PHP error: C:\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxxx/sites/all/modules/easy_booking-7.x-2.4/modules/system/system.admin.inc' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\xxxxx\xxxxxxx\includes\menu.inc on line 525